# difference between 2>&1 and >/dev/stdout for error stream redirection

Tags: stderr, io-redirection

Recently, I have encountered an error in running a certain imaging processing pipeline on our SGE-based cluster. Running the same pipeline locally not on the HPC cluster was fine.
Digging through log files, I found out the error which caused the crash:

```
/usr/bin/time: /dev/stdout: Not a directory
```

Looking further, I found the part in the script where in order to capture `time` command output, standard error was redirected to standard output through `/dev/stdout`. After further reading, I found that some file systems dont have `/dev/stdout`.

I edited the script to use `2>&1` instead and it worked fine. However, logging in to the HPC compute node and checking the existence of `/dev/stdout`, it showed that it exists after all:

```
# ls /dev/stdout -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Aug 24  2020 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

`uname`, `lsb_release` and `bash` versions were the same on the local PC and the compute node. Could someone explain the difference in redirecting standard error with `2>&1` and `>/dev/stdout`, and why my workaround worked?

Thank you!